# Ruby array into method

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I have an array in Ruby, like `["dog", "cat", bat"]`. How can I get an array in which each element is passed to a particular method? For example, if the method reverses the input string, then I expect to get `["god", "tac", "tab"]`. I know it's easy to iterate over the elements, pass them into the method, and put the results into an array. But is there a shorter way?

EDIT: I'd also **not** like to modify the original array.

Comment: `map` will not modify original array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
["dog", "cat", "bat"].map { |word| word.reverse }
```

or

```
["dog", "cat", "bat"].map &:reverse
```

Comment: No, it's a standard part of ruby syntax.  I just tried it in irb without any gems and it worked.

Comment: It's available in any version of Ruby that has [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc). I believe it was added in 1.8.7.